# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}$ bounded for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out if there is a finite constant $C$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}\leq C$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

I can see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{n^2}=mc$ for some finite constant $c$, but this is a weaker statement.

If I naively replace integers by reals and sums by integrals then I feel like the original series should be bounded.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{m}{(n+m)^2} = \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{\bigl( 1 + \frac{n}{m}\bigr)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use the hint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the integral comparison test,
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+m)^2}
=\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
\approx \int_m^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}
=\frac{-1}{x}\big|_m^{\infty}
=\frac{1}{m}
$,
so
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}
\approx 1
$.

To be more precise,
$\int_m^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}
> \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
>\int_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}
$,
so
$\frac{1}{m}
> \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
>\frac{1}{m+1}
$
or
$1
>\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{m}{n^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}
>(1-\frac1{m+1})
$.

Comment: Thanks. Early morning brain rot. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the extra detail to understand. This is a very nice technique for dealing with summation.

Comment: The basic idea is that, if $f(x)$ is decreasing,$\int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx < f(n) <\int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) dx$. Then sum this. 

If $f(x)$ is increasing,$\int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) dx < f(n) <\int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx$.

Answer (score 4):

Use that $\frac{m}{(n+m+1)(n+m)}= \frac{m}{(n+m)}-\frac{m}{(n+m+1)}$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. We can then see that your series is bounded by $C=1$ by comparing it with a telescoping series. More precisley:

For every $N, m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{m}{(n+m)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{m}{(n+m+1)^2} \leq $$ $$ \leq \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{m}{(n+m+1)(n+m)} = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{m}{(n+m)}-\frac{m}{(n+m+1)} = $$ $$= \frac{m}{m}-\frac{m}{(N+m+1)}=1 - \frac{m}{(N+m+1)} \leq 1 $$

Comment: Awesome. I tried to make a telescoping sum, but didn't know this trick of bounding the square by products of successive terms.

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad I could help.

Comment: Nice. And you can get a *lower* bound of $1-\frac1{m+1}$ by using $(n+m+1)^2 <(n+m+1)(n+m+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x>0$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{(n+x)^2}= x\cdot \psi'(x+1) = x\cdot\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log\Gamma(x+1)\tag{1} $$
but a way simpler bound is achieved by considering that, under the same assumption:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{(y+x)^2}\,dy = 1.\tag{2}$$
It is interesting to point that we may use this rather trivial bound to prove some version of Stirling's inequality: it is enough to divide the RHS of $(1)$ by $x$ and integrate twice.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I understand the integral... how can I apply this result to the sum?

Comment: @js86: yes, because you may see the sum as the integral of a piecewise-constant function that is upper-bounded by a simple integrable function.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the simple bound now. I'm going to accept @marty's answer because I actually needed the basic details, but I will study the digamma function approach too.

Comment: @js86: that's perfectly fine.